# Count number of NAs between 2 values by row in R

Tags: r, count, row, na

My data looks something like this:

```
db <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=10, nrow=3, 
                           c(3,NA,NA,4,5,NA,7,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,7,NA,8,9,NA,NA,4,6,NA,NA,7,8,11,5,10,NA,NA,NA), byrow = TRUE))

db
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  3 NA NA  4  5 NA  7 NA NA  NA
2 NA NA  7 NA  8  9 NA NA  4   6
3 NA NA  7  8 11  5 10 NA NA  NA
```

For each row, I'm trying to count the number of NAs that appear between the first and last non-NA element (I have numbers and characters) **by row**.

The output should be something like this:

```
db$na.tot <- c(3, 3, 0)
db
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 na.tot
1  3 NA NA  4  5 NA  7 NA NA  NA      3
2 NA NA  7 NA  8  9 NA NA  4   6      3
3 NA NA  7  8 11  5 10 NA NA  NA      0
```

Where `na.tot` represents the number of NAs observed between the first and last non-NA elements by row (between 3 and 7, 7 and 6 and 7 and 10 in rows 1, 2 and 3 respectively).

Does anyone have a simple solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
require(data.table)
z<-as.data.table(which(!is.na(db),arr.ind=TRUE))
setkey(z,row,col)
z[,list(NAs=last(col)-first(col)-.N+1),by=row]
#   row NAs
#1:   1   3
#2:   2   3
#3:   3   0
```